# PutObjectAsync stop code running at the first run - No exception throw

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to create an XML using MemoryStream and XMLWriter then passing the MemoryStream to PutObjectRequest but always at the first that it runs the lambda function stop running after trying to use PutObjectAsync, there is no EXCEPTION happening. If I invoke the test Function again for the second time, it works.

As I want to trigger it to be running regularly it would never create and save the XML file into the bucket that I am trying to generate. It seems that needs to run 2 times, one after another.

Anyone now what si wrong with my code?

```cs
try{
    var fileNameBuilder = string.Format("{0}.{1}-WL.xml", coItem.ToString(), fileEmissionDatetimeString);

 using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memStream, XMLHelper.xmlWriterSettings))
                    {
                        context.Logger.LogLine($"Writing file: " + fileNameBuilder);
                        writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"");
                        writer.WriteStartElement("data");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("source", "1");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("target", "0");

                        writer.WriteStartElement("list");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("item_nb", CoLists.Count.ToString());


                        writer.WriteStartElement("co");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("id", coItem.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("constitution", fileEmissionDatetimeString);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("item_nb", items.Where(i => i.Id == coItem).Count().ToString());

                        foreach (var item in items.Where(i => i.Id == coItem))
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement("item");
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("cm", item.ContextMark);
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("obu", item.HexAlias);
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("vc", item.VehicleClass.ToString());
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("vrn", item.VehicleRegistration);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            XMLRows++;
                        }

                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        writer.WriteEndDocument();
                        writer.Flush();
                        writer.Close();

                        context.Logger.LogLine($"XMLRows: " + XMLRows);

                        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
                        {
                            BucketName = SrcFilesBucket,
                            Key = SrcXMLPathBucket + "/" + fileNameBuilder,
                            ContentType = "text/xml",
                            InputStream = memStream
                        };

                        // Put object
                        var res = await _s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);

                        if (res.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            context.Logger.LogLine($"Finished coItem: " + coItem + " | File: " + fileNameBuilder);
                        }
 }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
            {
                if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null && (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") || amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                {
                    throw new SecurityException("Invalid Amazon S3 credentials - data was not uploaded.", amazonS3Exception);
                }

                throw new HttpRequestException("Unspecified error attempting to upload data: " + amazonS3Exception.Message, amazonS3Exception);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine($"ERROR - During generation of XML.");
                context.Logger.LogLine(ex.Message);
                context.Logger.LogLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
```

Anyone now what si wrong with my code?

Comment: On a side note use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`, that preserves the stack trace.

Comment: Have you checked if your Lambda function runs into a timeout? Sounds a bit like it if you don't get an exception or similar... You might want to check what happens if you upload just a small file in a hello-world style. Does it work at the first run?

Comment: @s.hesse the function it doesn't take that long to run... Like 10 seconds in total. and I set up the maximum already 900 seconds.